# How to use padding on panel control?

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a PanelControl to which I'm adding a simple padding. But it seems like it's not working.

How to do padding please ?

Here is my code

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim Panel As New DevExpress.XtraEditors.PanelControl
    Dim Button As New DevExpress.XtraEditors.SimpleButton

    Panel.Padding = New Padding(15)

    Panel.Parent = Me
    Button.Parent = Panel

End Sub
```

When running this code, the button created inside the panel doesn't have any space with the panel as expected.

Thanks

Comment: It is a 3rd party control so always hard to figure out what it is supposed to do.  Looking at the DevExpress docs, it's primary goal in life is to support custom look-and-feel, skinning.  It just inherits Padding from the base Control class.  Which doesn't come alive until the derived control implements automatic layout, like Winforms' FlowLayoutPanel and TableLayoutPanel.  And Winform's Panel doesn't.  So simple explanation is that it just doesn't use the property.  You'll have to set the button's Location yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this extra line might help you.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
Dim Panel As New DevExpress.XtraEditors.PanelControl
Dim Button As New DevExpress.XtraEditors.SimpleButton

Panel.AutoSize = True 'Adding this line should solve your problem
Panel.Padding = New Padding(15)

Panel.Parent = Me
Button.Parent = Panel

End Sub
```

> Please let me know if it worked for anyone...

Answer (score 0):

more than likely because the item in the panel is created before the padding is set. The location of the item in the panel is determined relative by the properties of the panel. try setting the padding before the element is created.

Comment: No, you didn't take padding and put it under your dim button new. and don't down vote this answer because i tested it myself.